# Babel [karma-babel-preprocessor] Not Converting ES6->ES5 for Karma Tests

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, babeljs

We have installed karma, which is using mocha and chai for tests. We are trying to integrate babel straight into karma using karma-babel-preprocessor, to do the converting of our ES6 files into ES5 to be run. Using mocha individually works with babel, i.e. a mocha test command, but we try to use karma instead it doesn't work.

karma.conf.js snippet:

```
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],

// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
   'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
   'test/**/*_spec.js': ['babel']
},

"babelPreprocessor": {
    options: {
        presets: ['es2015'],
        sourceMap: 'inline'
    },   
    filename: function(file) {
        return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
    },
    sourceFileName: function(file) {
        return file.originalPath;
    }
},

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'src/**/*.js',
  'test/**/*_spec.js'
],
```

package.json snippets:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
},

"babel": {
  "presets": ["es2015"]
},

"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
  "chai": "^3.4.1",
  "karma": "^0.13.15",
  "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
  "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
  "karma-mocha": "^0.2.1",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
  "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
  "redux": "^3.0.4"
}
```

We get the following error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports
  at Users/alexgurr/BT/FutureVoice/trunk/Portal/server/src/login.es5.js:3
```

When we evaluate the JS files being loaded, they haven't been converted to ES5, hence the syntax 'export' is still present.

We don't want to use any other frameworks for conversion, ie. webpack, browserify etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Karma runs your component & tests on browsers. If you want to test your node modules, use node runners like jasmine, mocha. You don't need Karma for this, and in fact is wrong to use it as it's a different runtime.

Answer (score 13):

I've been struggling for the past few hours with the same issue. I'm not sure if your use case is the same as mine, but I finally figured it out.

Code under test `src/foo.js`:

```
var foo = "foo value";
export default foo;
```

Test code `tests/foo.spec.js`:

```
import foo from "../src/foo.js";
describe('Foo', function() {
    it('should be "foo value"', function() {
        expect(foo).toBe('foo value');
    });
});
```

`karma.conf.js` file before:

```
{
    // other configs
    files: [
       'src/**/*.js',
       'tests/**/*.spec.js',
    ],
    preprocessors: {
       'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
       'tests/**/*.spec.js': ['babel'],
    },

    babelPreprocessor: {
        options: {
            "presets": ["es2015"]
        }
    }
}
```

This yielded the `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports` error you saw.

The fix:

- `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd`
- Add following to `karma.conf.js`

  ```
  babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
          "presets": ["es2015"],
          "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-umd"]
      }
  }
  ```

Then the error went away.

Also, note that the following `export` declarations ([which I believe should be correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)) do not work.

```
// exports an object
export default var foo = "something";

// exports undefined
export var bar = "something else";
```

Comment: This was the answer I needed. I didn't want to add Webpack or Browserify since I'm just working on Node. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove all webpack configs :)!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you still didn't bundle/wrap your files to be able to execute CommonJS modules in the browser (because Babel transpile es2015 modules into CommonJS and CJS is default module system for node, not for browsers where Karma run its tests). So your options are:

- Use [karma-commonjs wrapper](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs) (if you want to add all your dependencies manualy)
- Use [browserify](https://github.com/Nikku/karma-browserify) bundler with [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) plugin
- Use [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack) bundler

Comment: Yep.  https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor This page says "babel and karma-babel-preprocessor only convert ES6 modules to CommonJS/AMD/SystemJS/UMD. If you choose CommonJS, you still need to resolve and concatenate CommonJS modules on your own. We recommend karma-browserify + babelify or webpack + babel-loader in such cases."

ie... we can convert it to ES2015 or whatever, but we don't deal with modules so you need another preprocessor after babel to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need babel, not just the preset.

`npm i babel --save-dev`

I have almost the same configuration on one of my project, meaning letting karma pre-process my file on the fly, and the only difference for me is that I have installed babeljs also.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Obviously, files _was_ transpiled. Probably, Babel just was installed globally (`npm install -g babel`) to keep local `node_modules` from growing uncontrollably